latex hyperref choicemenu default value has not tick on chromium
I created an acroform in latex using hyperref and choicemenu as follows:
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}      
 \usepackage{fancyvrb}         
 \usepackage{hyperref}%
 \usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\CustomRadio}[1]{%
\tikz\draw (0,0) circle(0.15) node[anchor=center] {#1}; }
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{itemize}
 \item [A] {\hspace*{-0.65cm}\ChoiceMenu[radio, name=1, height=9pt,  backgroundcolor={}]{}{={A}}}                  A
 \item [B] {\hspace*{-0.65cm}\ChoiceMenu[radio, name=1, height=9pt,  backgroundcolor={}]{}{={B}}}                  B
\item [C] {\hspace*{-0.65cm}\ChoiceMenu[radio, name=1, height=9pt,  backgroundcolor={}]{}{={C}}}                  C
\item [D] {\hspace*{-0.65cm}\ChoiceMenu[radio, name=1, height=9pt, default=D,   backgroundcolor={}]{}{={D}}}                 D
\end{itemize}
\end{Form}
\end{document}

I see in chromium-based browsers that the deault value is set correctly (I have a Python script that reads the set values) but the tick is not shown on the PDF. I also added the "checked" flag with no success.

PDF-related functionality is often viewer-dependent.
